# Accessing Command line options passed to QGIS exe

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am using QGIS 2.8, I am passing the raster image along with the qgis-bin.exe from the command prompt. Is there a way to access the name of the raster being passed along the exe in my plugin?

Comment: Perhaps you can [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/192951/edit) your question to include the code you use to pass the raster to the qgis-bin.exe? This could help potential answerers =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a way.

Imagine you launch QGIS this way from the command prompt:

```
$ qgis /geodata/my_raster.tif
```

Open the QGIS Python Console and type this command:

```
QgsApplication.arguments()[1:]
```

You should get a list of arguments passed to QGIS from the command line:

```
[u'/geodata/my_raster.tif']
```

To get the raster file name you could do something like this:

```
import os.path
args = QgsApplication.arguments()[1:]
print os.path.splitext( os.path.basename( args[0] ) )[0]
```

Which, in this case, returns:

```
my_raster
```